# Cant quite get mobile navbar working

Tags: html, css, navbar

Trying to make my mobile navbar not coming out quite right. Anyone see the problem? I have only a couple months experience, need a quick hand of help. Much appreciated!

As you can see it doesnt display the navbar right at all. The contact page isnt clickable.Its missing the Services link

```
*******************
    NAV MENU MOBILE  
******************* 
-->
<div class="menu-wrap mobile">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-menu"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2 no-padding">
        <nav class="nav-menu">
          <button class="menu-toggle">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="icon"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="menu-item active menu-item-has-children">
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
              <a>Hosting</a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="hosting.html">Shared Hosting</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="reseller.html">Reseller Hosting</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="cloud.html">Cloud VPS</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="servers.html">Dedicated Server</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="domains.html">Domains</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
              <a href="blog.html>Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
              <a href="services.html>Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-last">
                <a class="menu-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYFad.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="services.html>Services</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="services.html">Services</a>
```

You left out the second `"`.

Answer (score 0):

In those two links...

```
          <a href="blog.html>Blog</a>

          <a href="services.html>Services</a>
```

...the closing quote of the `href`attribute is missing. Should be

```
          <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>

          <a href="services.html">Services</a>
```